# Foreach no PHP pula a primeira passagem

Tags: php

Ainda sou novo com PHP, então, quem for ajudar, peço paciência, kkk.
O `foreach` está no final do código, antes é só o texto dos artigos

Fiz um `foreach` para concatenar o *ID* de um elemento `<ul>`, ele faz a concatenação correta, mas, pula uma passagem.

```
<?php

// Variável das palavras chaves
$encontraTitulo = "TÍTULO";
$encontraCapitulo = "CAPÍTULO";
$encontraArtigo = "Art.";
$concatenaHierarquia = "";
// Variável dos valores para concatenar
$valorTitulo = "";
$valorCapitulo = "";
$valorArtigo = "";
// Lê conteúdo do txt
$documento = 'TÍTULO 1
      Dos Princípios Fundamentais

      Art. 1º A República Federtico.

      Parágrafo único. Todo o poder emana do povo, que o exerce por meio de representantes eleitos ou diretamente, nos termos desta Constituição.

      Art. 2º São Poderes da União, independentes e harmônicos entre si, o Legislativo, o Executivo e o Judiciário.

      Art. 3º Constituem objetivos fundaação e reduzir as desigualdades sociais e regionais;

      IV - promover o bem de todos, sem preconceitos de origem, raça, sexo, cor, idade e quaisquer outras formas de discriminação.

      Art. 4º A República Federativao Brasil buscará a integração econômica, política, social e cultural dos povos da América Latina, visando à formação de uma comunidade latino-americana de nações.

      TÍTULO 2
      Dos Direitos e Garantias Fundamentais
      CAPÍTULO 1
      DOS DIREITOS E DEVERES INDIVIDUAIS E COLETIVOS

      Art. 5º Todos são iguais perante a lei,al Internacional a cuja criação tenha manifestado adesão. (Incluído pela Emenda Constitucional nº 45, de 2004)

      CAPÍTULO 2
      DOS DIREITOS SOCIAIS

      Art. 6º São direitocitucional nº 64, de 2010)

      Art. 7º São direitos dos trabalhadores urbanos 

      Art. 11. Nas empresas de mais de duzentos empregados, é assegurada a eleição de um representante destes com a finalidade exclusiva de promover-lhes o entendimento direto com os empregadores.

      CAPÍTULO 3
      DA NACIONALIDADE

      Art. 12. São brasilei

      CAPÍTULO 4
      DOS DIREITOS POLÍTICOS

      Art. 14. A soberania popular será e.

      Art. 16. A lei que alterar o processo eleitoral entrará em vigor na data de sua publicação, não se aplicando à eleição que ocorra até um ano da data de sua vigência. (Redação dada pela Emenda Constitucional nº 4, de 1993)

      CAPÍTULO 5
      DOS PARTIDOS POLÍTICOS

      Art. 17. É livre a 

      TÍTULO 3
      Da Organização do Estado
      CAPÍTULO 1
      DA ORGANIZAÇÃO POLÍTICO-ADMINISTRATIVA

      Art. 18. A organização polít

      CAPÍTULO 2
      DA UNIÃO

      Art. 20. São bens da Una de lei federal sobre normas gerais suspende a eficácia da lei estadual, no que lhe for contrário.

      CAPÍTULO 3
      DOS ESTADOS FEDERADOS

      Art. 25. Os Estados organizam-se e regem-se pelas Constituições e leis que adotarem, observados os princípios desta Constituição.

      § 1º - São reservadasei

      Art. 66. A Casa na qual tenhanado a promulgará, e, se este não o fizer em igual prazo, caberá ao Vice-Presidente do Senado fazê-lo.

      Art. 67. A matéria constante de projeto de lei rejeitado somente poderá constituir objeto de novo projeto, na mesma sessão legislativa, mediante proposta da maioria absoluta dos membros de qualquer das Casas do Congresso Nacional.';
// Função para limpar linhas em branco
$documento = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $documento);
// Converte em linhas
$linhas = explode("\n", $documento);
foreach($linhas as $novalinha) {
    // Variável dos valores para concatenar
    $numbers = '';
    $letters = '';
    $concatena = $valorTitulo . $valorCapitulo . $valorArtigo;
    // Envolve cada linha em um parágrafo
    $novalinhas = "<li><p>" . $novalinha . "</p></li>";
    // Verifica se tem o texto Linha na linha
    $procuraTitulo = strpos($novalinhas, $encontraTitulo);
    $procuraCapitulo = strpos($novalinhas, $encontraCapitulo);
    $procuraArtigo = strpos($novalinhas, $encontraArtigo);
    // Verifica se tem o texto Linha na linha
    if ($procuraTitulo === false) {
        if ($procuraCapitulo === false) {
            if ($procuraArtigo === false) {
                // Se não encontrar nada
                echo $novalinhas;
                // Se não encontrar artigo
            }
            else {
                // Captura o número do artigo na linha para atribuir na ID
                $artigo = explode(" ", $novalinhas);
                // Define as variações para serem excluídas e remove variações
                $caracteres = array(
                    "º",
                    "."
                );
                $artigos = str_replace($caracteres, "", $artigo[1]);
                // Atribui à valorArtigo a string "_artigo + nº"
                $valorArtigo = '_artigo' . $artigos;
                // Atribui à valorArtigo a value
                $value = $valorArtigo;
                // Separa a palavra do número
                for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
                    if (is_numeric($value[$i])) $numbers.= $value[$i];
                    else $letters.= $value[$i];
                }
                // Verifica se é a palavra artigo
                if ($letters == "artigo") {
                    // Mantém o valorArtigo
                    $valorArtigo = $valorArtigo;
                    // Mantém o valorArtigo
                }
                else {
                    // Verifica está definido
                    if (isset($valorArtigo)) {
                        // Mantém o valorArtigo
                        $valorArtigo = $valorArtigo;
                    }
                    else {
                        // Limpa o valorArtigo
                        $valorArtigo = "";
                    }
                }
                // Monta a ul com o id concatenado
                echo "</ul>";
                echo '<ul id="' . $concatena . '" class="artigo">';
                echo $novalinhas;
            }
            // Se foi capturado a palavra subseção
        }
        else {
            $contatenaCapitulo = 1;
            // Captura o número romano da Subseção para atribuir na ID
            $cap = explode(" ", $novalinhas);
            $caracteres = array(
                "CAPÍTULO"
            );
            $caps = $cap[1];
            $valorCapitulo = '_capitulo' . $caps;
            $value = $valorCapitulo;
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
                if (is_numeric($value[$i])) $numbers.= $value[$i];
                else $letters.= $value[$i];
            }
            if ($letters == "capitulo") {
                $valorArtigo = "";
            }
            else {
                if (isset($valorCapitulo)) {
                    $valorCapitulo = $valorCapitulo;
                }
                else {
                    $valorCapitulo = "";
                }
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo '<ul id="' . $concatena . '" class="capitulo">';
            echo $novalinhas;
        }
    }
    else {
        $contatenaTitulo = 1;
        $tit = explode(" ", $novalinhas);
        $caracteres = array(
            "TÍTULO"
        );
        $tits = $tit[1];
        $valorTitulo = '_titulo' . $tits;
        $value = $valorTitulo;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
            if (is_numeric($value[$i])) $numbers.= $value[$i];
            else $letters.= $value[$i];
        }
        if ($letters == "titulo") {
            $valorCapitulo = "";
            $valorArtigo = "";
        }
        else {
            if (isset($valorTitulo)) {
                $valorTitulo = $valorTitulo;
            }
            else {
                $valorTitulo = "";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo '<ul id="' . $concatena . '" class="titulo">';
        echo $novalinhas;
    }
}
?>
```

### [**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/CcVDpw)

Comment: Qual passagem não é processada? teu código parece funcionar, embora tenha certas coisas desnecessárias nele. *Futuramente, se possível,  coloque apenas o código necessário*, e um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), assim vai aumentar as chances de mais pessoas entenderem o problema e postarem uma resposta que atenda ao que você quer. =)

Comment: @qmechanik, , ele faz a leitura correta, só que uma passagem depois, era como se todos os ids das uls, pulassem para a ul debaixo e a primeira id fica vazia. Eu tentei reduzir ao máximo o código, kkk, mas como ainda snão sou muito experiente, talvez tenha linhas que não precisaria ter colocado, se puder me falar quais eram desnecessárias, eu agradeço

Comment: Tipo essa verificação: `if (isset($valorTitulo)){ $valorTitulo = $valorTitulo;}else {$valorTitulo = "";}`. Na pergunta tem aproximadamente 200 linhas de código, o que torna bem mais difícil entender qual o trecho está causando o problema. Testei o seu código aqui e funcionou, qual é o objetivo real do código? é somente adicionar a cada linha da variável `$documento` o elemento `<ul>`, ou tem algo a mais? qual a **passagem é pulada**?

Comment: É a primeira passagem, daí o id do título1 um vai para o id do artigo 1 e o id do artigo 1, vai para o id do artigo 2, e assim por diante, eu quis fazer com que ele concatenasse a hierarquia dos artigos, então o titulo1, fica com o id de titulo1, o id do artigo 1, ficaria com o id titulo1artigo1 e assim, por diante, eu consegui fazer ele concatenar certinho, mas, parece que o código pula a primeira passagem, ou ele captura a primeira passagem e aplica o id na passagem seguinte

Comment: Veja se é isso **http://pastebin.com/n03q6gdG**.

Comment: É isso!!! mas o que você alterou? onde estava errando?

Comment: Postei uma resposta, veja se consegue entender o que foi. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira passagem não é processada porque na linha onde é verificado a ocorrência da palavra *`TÍTULO`*, usando a função [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php), é retornado a posição numérica da primeira ocorrência de *`TÍTULO`*, *7*, que por sua vez é avaliada como [`True`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.boolean.php), e entra no bloco de código `Else` do primeiro `If` do código, e no momento onde é atribuído o *ID* do elemento `<ul>`, a variável `$concatena` vem vazia, veja abaixo.

```
$valorTitulo = $valorCapitulo = $valorArtigo = "";
....
...
foreach($linhas as $novalinha) {
  ....
  $concatena = $valorTitulo. $valorCapitulo. $valorArtigo; // Vazia! devido a primeira operação do foreach
  ...
  $procuraTitulo = strpos($novalinhas, $encontraTitulo); // primeira passagem, resultado: 7
  ...
  if ($procuraTitulo === false) {
    ....
    ...
  else { // A primeira passagem é processada daqui em diante
    ....
    ...
    echo "</ul>";
    echo '<ul id="'. $concatena. '" class="titulo">'; // Vazio!
     echo $novalinhas;
  }
```

A solução é trocar a variável `$concatena` por `$valorTitulo`:

```
echo "</ul>";
echo '<ul id="' . $valorTitulo. '" class="titulo">'; // Agora tem um valor!
echo $novalinhas;
```